# GitPython: How to detect if file is deleted?

Tags: gitpython

I'm writing an automated script to process staged/unstaged files for a pre-commit hook.
I would like to be able to know if a file is marked as deleted by git ("D " or " D" in `git status --porcelain -- {filename}`) so that I can remove it from the list. I would like to do so through the GitPython API if possible.

Previously attempted steps:

- I couldn't find in the documentation any reference to "delete" that related to this use case
- Using `dir(item)` where `item` is a Diffable from `repo.index.diff(None)` reveals the following members:

  `['NULL_BIN_SHA', 'NULL_HEX_SHA', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_handle_diff_line', '_index_from_patch_format', '_index_from_raw_format', '_pick_best_path', 'a_blob', 'a_mode', 'a_path', 'a_rawpath', 'b_blob', 'b_mode', 'b_path', 'b_rawpath', 'change_type', 'copied_file', 'deleted_file', 'diff', 'new_file', 'raw_rename_from', 'raw_rename_to', 're_header', 'rename_from', 'rename_to', 'renamed', 'renamed_file', 'score']`

out of which `deleted_file` seems to be the only sensible candidate - but it doesn't seem to reflect the result of git status --porcelain since all deleted files in git status are set to deleted_file=False (same as non-deleted ones).

For now I am relying on git directly to assert if a file is deleted or not:

```
def _is_deleted(path: str):
    files = _gitstatus()
    return 'D' in files[path]


@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def _gitstatus():
    child = subprocess.Popen(["git", "status", "--porcelain"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = [stream.decode('utf-8') if stream is not None else '' for stream in child.communicate()]
    if child.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception(err)
    files = {
        line[3:]: tuple(line[0:2])
        for line in out.split('\n')
    }
    return files
```

but I'd much prefer using the GitPython API if possible. Any idea how to achieve the equivalent result of the above function?

Comment: If you want pure gitpython answers, snip off the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this answer your question?

This is using the [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library, it's a bit involved but you can get the similar result to as `git status` using the `Repo.index.diff()`. This function is similar if not the same as the [git.diff.Diff](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.diff.Diff) and you can see how to filter files on the docs there.

```py
from git import Repo

repo = Repo()

if repo.is_dirty():

    index = repo.index
    
    for obj in index.diff(None).iter_change_type('D'):
        print('File path', obj.b_path)
        print('Change type', obj.change_type)
        print('Is deleted', obj.deleted_file)
```

---

```
(git-test) ➜  (01/09 20:18) /tmp/git-test git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    test.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        git-test.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


(git-test) ➜  (01/09 20:19) /tmp/git-test git:(master) ✗ python git-test.py
File path test.txt
Change type D
Is deleted True
```

---

### Updated to show Untracked, Staged and Deleted files

```py
from git import Repo

repo = Repo()

if repo.is_dirty():

    index = repo.index

    print('Untracked files', repo.untracked_files)

    print('Staged files', [item.a_path for item in repo.index.diff('HEAD')])

    for obj in index.diff(None):
        print('File path', obj.b_path)
        print('Change type', obj.change_type)
        print('Is deleted', obj.deleted_file)
```

---

```
(git-test) ➜  (02/09 13:58) /tmp/git-test git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   test-2.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    test.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .idea/
        git-test.py

(git-test) ➜  (02/09 13:58) /tmp/git-test git:(master) ✗ python git-test.py
Untracked files ['.idea/.gitignore', '.idea/git-test.iml', '.idea/misc.xml', '.idea/modules.xml', '.idea/vcs.xml', 'git-test.py']
Staged files ['test-2.txt']
File path test.txt
Change type D
Is deleted True
```

Comment: I think that's a great answer! Since my goal is to list files that are unstaged/staged and that are not deleted, I'd use `for obj in index.diff(None) if obj.change_type != 'D'` instead :)
If you want to update your answer to reflect that, I can update the question to be more precise and then accept your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I couldn't get it to work the way you suggested but, I've managed to get the staged files by diffing the `HEAD`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, I would use :

- `git diff --name-status` to get the status of tracked files compared to the index,
- `git diff --staged --name-status` to get the status of staged files compared to the current commit.

---

I think you can extract the same information from GitPython's [diff api](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#obtaining-diff-information) :

> ```
> hcommit = repo.head.commit
> hcommit.diff()                  # diff tree against index
> hcommit.diff('HEAD~1')          # diff tree against previous tree
> hcommit.diff(None)              # diff tree against working tree
>
> index = repo.index
> index.diff()                    # diff index against itself yielding empty diff
> index.diff(None)                # diff index against working copy
> index.diff('HEAD')              # diff index against current HEAD tree
> ```

`git diff` would be `index.diff(None)`, `git diff --staged` would be `index.diff('HEAD')` or `hcommit.diff()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer LeGEC. This does not answer the question however - I know how to obtain the files, just not how to determine if they are deleted

Comment: true :) I was hoping the object returned by `index.diff()`, for example, would contain something that indicates "that file has been added / modified / deleted", but I'm not fluent in GitPython.

Comment: I would otherwise suggest to parse the output of `git diff --name-status` or `git status --porcelain` once, to get the complete list of information you need.

Comment: Updated OP with better parser to match your suggestion :)
It's a working workaround, but I really want to know if it's doable with GitPython

Comment: I don't have time to dig deep in GitPython's documentation, it looks like you can get a [DiffIndex](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.diff.DiffIndex) at some point,  and some properties (like `change_type = ('A', 'C', 'D', 'R', 'M', 'T')`) can be either queried or inspected or ...

Comment: That sounds like a great pick! change_type sounds to be exactly what I am looking for